# OleAutoObj is not opening Excel application in my PC

Tags: excel, ole, ibm-doors

Following dxl code is not opening an excel application in my PC. I suspect an earlier dxl script which I ran. It activated Excel Ole Objects and opened them. How to close all excel processes which opened by earlier dxl script?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
OleAutoObj objExcel = oleCreateAutoObject("Excel.Application")
if (objExcel != null){
bool excelVisible
oleGet(objExcel, "Visible", excelVisible)
if (excelVisible == false){
olePut(objExcel, "Visible", true)
}
}
```

-Ashok Anumula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a perm `oleCloseAutoObject( objExcel )`

Comment: I tried oleCloseAutoObject. Still dxl not opening Excel Application
-Excel launches manually
-Excel export from DOORS working
-I am able to open Excel.Application from WORD VBA with following code:
 Sub exop()
 Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
 Dim openExcel As Workbook
 Set excelApp = New Excel.Application
 Set openExcel = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Ashok\file.xlsx")
 excelApp.Visible = True
End Sub
Please let me know how to check following.
"is the path behind the executable registered in Windows registry to the Excel.Application object correct?"

Comment: Well, if you ask whether Excel is installed correctly, you could open a PowerShell and do the two commands `$a=New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application` and `echo $a`. 

When you say "is not opening an excel application" - do you mean that objExcel is null or that Excel cannot be made visible?

you could of course kill all processes "excel.exe"  with a command like `system "powershell -command 'Get-Process Excel | Stop-Process'"`, if that helps you.

Comment: objExcel is not null. Excel cannot be made visible.

Comment: I killed Excel processes using powershell. But no use. Still Excel Application is not visible.
objExcel is not null. Excel cannot be made visible.
The line olePut(objExcel, "Visible", true) is not working.
Mike, if you have DOORS dxl, please check the code mentioned in question opens Excel Application or not in your PC.

Comment: it works for me, but it seems that the OLE Automation Object is bound to the script. So, to actually see that Excel is visible, you might want to add a `sleep_ 10000` as the last line, so that Excel pops up on your screen. When the script has finished, the Object is auto-destroyed again

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Then please mark the question as answered / accept the answer.